# Loop through multiple objects json data

Tags: php, json

I am trying to loop through JSON data to get values of "cell" & corresponding "label". Stuck on how to loop multiple array and objects

```
<?php
$url = file_get_contents("data.json");
$results = json_decode($url, true);
foreach ($results as $key => $value) {

}
?>
```

JSON data https://jsfiddle.net/6ft3vx35/

```
[null,null,{"rows":[{"cells":[{"value":"755","formatted_value":"755"}],"label":"Twitter"},{"cells":[{"value":"151","formatted_value":"151"}],"label":"Online News"},{"cells":[{"value":"107","formatted_value":"107"}],"label":"Blogs"},{"cells":[{"value":"28","formatted_value":"28"}],"label":"Newspaper"},{"cells":[{"value":"17","formatted_value":"17"}],"label":"Facebook"},{"cells":[{"value":"10","formatted_value":"10"}],"label":"Instagram"},{"cells":[{"value":"2","formatted_value":"2"}],"label":"Forums"},{"cells":[{"value":"2","formatted_value":"2"}],"label":"TV/Radio"},{"cells":[{"value":"1","formatted_value":"1"}],"label":"Flickr"},{"cells":[{"value":"1","formatted_value":"1"}],"label":"News Agency"},{"cells":[{"value":"0","formatted_value":"0"}],"label":"Press Release"},{"cells":[{"value":"0","formatted_value":"0"}],"label":"Magazine"},{"cells":[{"value":"0","formatted_value":"0"}],"label":"Radio Broadcast"},{"cells":[{"value":"0","formatted_value":"0"}],"label":"TV Broadcast"},{"cells":[{"value":"0","formatted_value":"0"}],"label":"Print Other"},{"cells":[{"value":"0","formatted_value":"0"}],"label":"Local Weekly"},{"cells":[{"value":"0","formatted_value":"0"}],"label":"Papers Regional \u0026 Local Newspapers"},{"cells":[{"value":"0","formatted_value":"0"}],"label":"National Newspapers"},{"cells":[{"value":"0","formatted_value":"0"}],"label":"Print News"},{"cells":[{"value":"0","formatted_value":"0"}],"label":"Print Magazine"},{"cells":[{"value":"0","formatted_value":"0"}],"label":"External"},{"cells":[{"value":"0","formatted_value":"0"}],"label":"Douban"},{"cells":[{"value":"0","formatted_value":"0"}],"label":"Vine"},{"cells":[{"value":"0","formatted_value":"0"}],"label":"Pinterest"},{"cells":[{"value":"0","formatted_value":"0"}],"label":"VKontakte"},{"cells":[{"value":"0","formatted_value":"0"}],"label":"Weibo"},{"cells":[{"value":"0","formatted_value":"0"}],"label":"Dailymotion"},{"cells":[{"value":"0","formatted_value":"0"}],"label":"Vimeo"},{"cells":[{"value":"0","formatted_value":"0"}],"label":"Soundcloud"},{"cells":[{"value":"0","formatted_value":"0"}],"label":"Mixcloud"},{"cells":[{"value":"0","formatted_value":"0"}],"label":"Foursquare"},{"cells":[{"value":"0","formatted_value":"0"}],"label":"LinkedIn"},{"cells":[{"value":"0","formatted_value":"0"}],"label":"YouTube"},{"cells":[{"value":"0","formatted_value":"0"}],"label":"Google+"},{"cells":[{"value":"0","formatted_value":"0"}],"label":"Newsletter"}],"column_groups":[{"data_columns":[{"name":"Results","code":"COUNT","type":"number"}]}],"column_type":"","row_type":"","total_results":"1.1K","layers":[]}]
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Yes what is the actual problem that you wanted to ask please add some more detail to your question

Comment: He is trying to loop through the decoded JSON, I think that's obvious, OP do a `var_dump($results)`

Comment: _He is trying to loop through the decoded JSON.._ I've already read this... @MehdiBounya

Comment: @B001 I don't get what you mean

Comment: This is not a question, and unless the data itself is relevant, an example line would do with an expected output. You are also looping through, but you aren't actually doing anything with the variables in the loop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can iterate through [foreach()](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php)

```
foreach($results[2]['rows'] as $res){
   echo 'label is:-'.$res['label'].PHP_EOL;
   echo 'Cells Value is:-'.$res['cells'][0]['value'].PHP_EOL;
   echo 'Cells Formatted Value is:-'.$res['cells'][0]['formatted_value'].PHP_EOL;
}
```

Sample Output:-

1.https://eval.in/944780

2.https://eval.in/944788

Answer (score 1):

You need to iterate array like this

```
<?php
$url = file_get_contents("data.json");
$results = json_decode($url, true);
$rows = $results[2];
foreach ($rows as $row) {
    $label = $row["label"];
    foreach ($row["cells"] as $cell) {
         $value = $cell["value"];

         // do some stuff with $label and $value
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: You could do some explanation? a pure code answer isn't helping.